# Need Exercise to solve based on Linear Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have completed implementing **Operation** of Linear Linked List using **C**,

Now inorder to test my ability i need to solve some problems based on Linear Linked List, and there you people can help me by suggesting some problems/assignments ...
I think there is nothing wrong in asking this type of help from my community members .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Determine whether the linked list contains cycle or not.
2. In the circular linked list add new node at the end without traversing the list.
3. Reverse the list.
4. Print the nodes in the list in reverse order without reversing the list.
5. Make a list Circular linked list.
6. Sort the list.
7. Merge two sorted lists.

Comment: Out the list I have implemented number 3 & 4.
an you give some hints on what is a cyclic list ?

Comment: Do you cyclic linked list means Circular linked list ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Circular linked list. Add necessary changes in the answer.

Comment: Oh yes, I am trying to build it...
but its quite challenging !